# Is there a way to hide some default routes, but not all, from the API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following basic router setup:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    router = DefaultRouter()
else:
    router = SimpleRouter()

# Domains REST Routes:
router.register(r'domains', DomainViewSet)

# Domains Pin REST Routes:
router.register(r'domains/pin', DomainPinViewSet)
```

This gives:

[image]

However, what I would like to do is something like this:

```
# Domains REST Routes:
router.register(r'domains', DomainViewSet)

# Domains Pin REST Routes:
router.register(r'domains/pin', DomainPinViewSet, hide_from_view=True)
```

That is, only hide the route from the dynamically generated routes information...is there a way to do this?

Comment: why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood So, for the example above, "pinning domains" is a web application neccessity (creates a instance which links a Domain object to a User object - both FKs), but this is really not neccessary for the public exploring an overview of the main namespaces of the API.

Comment: What do you mean by *"public"* here? How did you obtain that screenshot? or where someone can found the `pin` API information?

Comment: @JPG So the API is available on https://api.domain.tld => you can of course make requests to the API over cURL etc etc but we want users to be able to visit the api in the browser to inspect public data. Although the `domains/pin` route is authenticated restricted (there's only a create and destroy action with this) ... so we just want to hide this route from any browser viewing.

Comment: So just "hidden" from this view, but still accessible.

Comment: So, after *"hiding"* the `pin` apis, will someone able to make cURL request to the same end-points if they aware of the end-points? (sorry that I'm a bit confused here)

Comment: @JPG Yes, if they are able to authenticate with the API before making the call. But we'd rather make that functionality a little bit "hidden"/undocumented.

Comment: Okay, So, if I understood correctly you are looking for somewhat [jsonrenderer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#jsonrenderer).

Comment: @JPG I think you have misunderstood. I have the JSON renderer working ok - we can curl all of the endpoints in our API. However, we want to hide them from the index mapping ... that's all, just hide them.